# Openlayers: Display feature labels

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I try to add labels of a vector I added in openlayers with a stylefunction. The function works for stroke, but no text is displayed and I can't find a solution for it.

My code is the following:

```
var myfeature = new ol.layer.Vector({
  title: '&nbsp; myfeature',
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: 'data/myfeature.geojson',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
  }),
  style: styleFunction
});

function styleFunction() {
  return [
  new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: [0, 0, 0, 1.0],
      width: 1,
      lineDash: [1, 5, 3, 5]
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      font: '50px Calibri'
      }),
      text: myfeature.get('label')
    })
  ];
}
```

The fault is probably in `text: myfeature.get('label')`, but I can't say what I do wrong nor worked anything else I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared `myfeature` as your layer.  OpenLayers passes individual features as a parameter of the style function, so you must add a parameter to the function and use that to get properties

```
function styleFunction(feature) {
  return [
  new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: [0, 0, 0, 1.0],
      width: 1,
      lineDash: [1, 5, 3, 5]
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      font: '50px Calibri'
      text: feature.get('label'),
      placement: 'line',
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#000'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#fff',
        width: 3
      })
    }),
  })
  ];
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't fix it, it's the same as before: The stroke style is applied, but no text appears. And I don't get an error message in firefox.

Comment: And one more thing: If I change the text to a string (text: 'Hello') I get the error message "TypeError: t.getFill is not a function"

Comment: If you are placing text on linestring features you either need a placement point geometry or must use `placement: 'line'`  It is also usual to specify stroke and fill style for the text, although OpenLayer will set defaults if not specified.

Comment: I didn't know about the placement, thanks! But I still get the same error as mentioned above "TypeError: t.getFill is not a function" and no labels are displayed

Comment: `text: ` was below the `}),` which closed the `ol.style.Text({`